# Can not make hibernate on UEFI (Secure boot)

Tags: boot, uefi, 16.04, hibernate

**How can I make hibernate my desktop in UEFI with Secure boot on.**

I used command "sudo pm-hibernate" to make hibernate my desktop but my machine did nothing (my desktop is booted up on UEFI with Secure boot on).
But, if I boot my desktop on UEFI with Secure boot off, Hibernation is normal.

Sorry for my English, thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently hibernation is disabled by design with secure boot, since modifying the stored memory content is a potential attack vector.

There seem to exist some kernel patches, which implement signed hibernate images

https://lwn.net/Articles/651274/

but I don't know whether there exist any usable packaged kernels for Ubuntu, which include those.