# Hibernation disappeared in Ubuntu 16.04 after a kernel upgrade

Tags: 16.04, hibernate

I enabled hibernation in a few computers by adding `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` with this content:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default]
  Identity=unix-user:*
  Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
  ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default for login1]
  Identity=unix-user:*
  Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
  ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate for multiple users by default in logind]
  Identity=unix-user:*
  Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
  ResultActive=yes
```

It worked well till a recent update on my ASUS X200MA.

The menu item disappeared and also the `com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` is not there any more. I added it again, but it did not change anything.

Also `pm-hibernate` command does not do anything and `dmesg` shows nothing.

How can I find out what has happened?

On other computers hibernation still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some effort to get a solution I recalled that recently I activated Secure Boot in UEFI for testing purposes.

It was enabled before, but it was not active because I did not enroll the keys.

After that the "Hibernate" menu item disappeared.

I have no idea how Secure Boot is related to the hibernation option, but after I disabled Secure Boot, it works again.

Comment: Apparently Secure Boot disables hibernate per this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/775707/145568  It's really rather annoying because a laptop that's hibernated on encrypted storage and has secure boot enabled ought to be rather... secure; much more so than one that's either just suspended to RAM or has secure boot disabled... wondering if Windows fares better in that space